# magento rest api (get products) is returning duplicate data

Tags: rest, magento, magento-1.9

i tried to retrieve all the products using magento rest api,

I used google chrome -> POSTMAN as restclient and specified the headers properly (Consumerkey, ConsumerSecret, token, token secret)

There are only 215 products in magento and i tried to access the products using restclient

https://domain.com/api/rest/products?type=rest&category_id=7&limit=100&page=1

Question :
on page no 3 it has to return only 15 products but it is returning 100 products, why? and if i specify page no as 4 or 5 or even 100000 means it is returning the response with duplicate data?